# CkEditor set cursor behind inserted Html

Tags: ckeditor

I insert some links to CkEditor by executing

```
editor.insertHtml(links.join('<br />'));
```

now, when I continue typing I will extend the text of the last link, since the cursor is for some reason before the closing `</a>` it seems.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have same problem and I cannot find solution....

Comment: Hi, yes I just inserted another blank `&nbsp` at the end.